# how fix error"Collection name must be a String" ,if my collection is called orders

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

#### when i run file `productinit` display this  *`error`*:

```
{
  imagePath: '/images/about/a1.png',
  productName: 'iphone 8+ ',
  price: 200,
  information: {
    displaySize: 6.5,
    storageCapacity: 64,
    CameraResolution: 16,
    numberOfSIM: 'Dual SIM',
    _id: new ObjectId("64c2519fc3c8f2e6189ed163")
  },
  _id: new ObjectId("64c2519fc3c8f2e6189ed162")
}
C:\courses\node-js\shopping-cart\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:54
        throw new error_1.MongoInvalidArgumentError('Collection name must be a String');
              ^

MongoInvalidArgumentError: Collection name must be a String
    at checkCollectionName (C:\courses\node-js\shopping-cart\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:54:15)
    at new Collection (C:\courses\node-js\shopping-cart\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:68:41)
    at Db.collection (C:\courses\node-js\shopping-cart\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:205:16)
    at NativeCollection.onOpen (C:\courses\node-js\shopping-cart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:46:34)
    at Connection.onOpen (C:\courses\node-js\shopping-cart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:680:27)
    at _setClient (C:\courses\node-js\shopping-cart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\connection.js:395:8)
    at NativeConnection.createClient (C:\courses\node-js\shopping-cart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\connection.js:298:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async NativeConnection.openUri (C:\courses\node-js\shopping-cart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:761:5)
    at async connectDB (C:\courses\node-js\shopping-cart\init\productinit.js:7:5) {
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}

Node.js v18.16.1
```

i dont know why display "Collection name must be a String" in spite of my collection="orders".
but when i use git bash in my terminal and use command mongoosh then

## `show dbs` i dont found my db or my collection.

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

### file productinit:

```
const product = require('../model/product');
const mongoose= require('mongoose');

const connectDB = async () => {
    await mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/orders');
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
  };
  connectDB();

const products = [
    new product({
        imagePath:"/images/about/a1.png",
        productName: "iphone 8+ ",
        price: 200,
        information:
        { 
        displaySize: 6.5,
        storageCapacity: 64,
        CameraResolution: 16,
        numberOfSIM: "Dual SIM"
        }}),

    new product({
        imagePath:"/images/about/a2.png",
        productName: "iphone 8 ",
        price: 240,
        information:
        { 
            displaySize: 5.5,
            storageCapacity: 64,
            CameraResolution: 16,
            numberOfSIM: "Dual SIM"
        }}),
 
     new product({
         imagePath:"/images/about/a3.png",
         productName: "iphone 7+ ",
         price: 180,
         information:
            { 
                displaySize: 6.1,
                storageCapacity: 64,
                CameraResolution: 15,
                numberOfSIM: "Dl SIM"
        }}),
    
    new product({
        imagePath:"/images/about/a4.png",
        productName: "iphone 7 ",
        price: 180,
        information:
                { 
                    displaySize: 6.1,
                    storageCapacity: 32,
                    CameraResolution: 15,
                    numberOfSIM: "Dl SIM"
        }}),
        
    new product({
            imagePath:"/images/about/a5.png",
            productName: "iphone 7+ ",
            price: 180,
            information:
            { 
                displaySize: 6.1,
                storageCapacity: 64,
                CameraResolution: 15,
                numberOfSIM: "Dl SIM"
        }}),

    new product({
                imagePath:"/images/about/a6.png",
                productName: "iphone 7+ ",
                price: 180,
                information:
                { 
                    displaySize: 6.1,
                    storageCapacity: 64,
                    CameraResolution: 15,
                    numberOfSIM: "Dl SIM"
        }}),
        
]


async function saveProducts() {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/orders');
    
        for (const product of products) 
        {
            console.log(product);
            const doc = await product.save();
            console.log("Product saved:", doc);
        }
         mongoose.disconnect();
    } catch (error) {console.error("Error saving products:", error);}
    }
    saveProducts();
```

### file product.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    imagePath:{type:String, required:true},
    productName:{type:String, required:true},
    price:{type:Number, required:true},
    information:
    {
        required:true,
        type:
        {
            displaySize: Number,
            storageCapacity:Number,
            CameraResolution: Number,
            numberOfSIM: String
        }
    }
});

const product = mongoose.model("product", productSchema, { schema: true });
module.exports = product;
```

#### when i use git bash in my terminal and use command mongoosh then show dbs i dont found my db or my collection.

#### i found admin & config & local